# How to enforce script command to save the output even if my ssh session is closed

Tags: linux, bash

I have done a test.

If i start the `script` command and run some commands, if a suddenly lost my ssh session (simply closing putty program, for example), the output is not saved. Is there some way to enforce to save the output without type `exit` or `ctrl + d`?

ex:

```
[oracle@dbnode1 ~]$ script test
Script started, file is test
[oracle@dbnode1 ~]$
[oracle@dbnode1 ~]$ echo "hello"
hello
[oracle@dbnode1 ~]$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.4G        2.8G         77M        3.4G        4.6G        1.0G
Swap:          8.0G         19M        8.0G
[oracle@dbnode1 ~]$
```

***Suddenly lost my ssh connection.***

I open a new session and there is nothing in the file.

```
[oracle@dbnode1 ~]$ ls -l test
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall 0 Sep  8 19:54 test
[oracle@dbnode1 ~]$ cat test
[oracle@dbnode1 ~]$
```

Comment: Your session hasn't noticed you've gone. If you type `who` you'll see you're still apparently logged on. So `script` hasn't got round to writing output to its log file

Comment: There is nothing that indicates that your session was disconnected. If that is a concern, then you can use an application like screen or tmux so that your processes will continue running in case that does happen.

Comment: when your terminal closes any commands associated with the session will get a hup signal, which will force them to close, even if they were running in the background.  there is a command called `nohup` that will allow you to run a shell script and detach it from the controlling terminal so it will not get that signal.

Answer (score 1):

You should start your script with `nohup`, which will disable a handle of `HUP` signal which a ssh session is sending to its child processes before it's terminated.

```
$ nohup /.script test
```